# Cassandra Optimization

Tags: cassandra, change-data-capture

I have a huge Cassandra table. over 2 billion rows and keeps growing. Systems are only supposed to write into this table, but if anyone updates or deletes any values, I want to notify you. No notification is needed for inserts.
How can we achieve this? Both batch and real-time streaming approaches are fine.

I know there are Cassandra triggers, but not sure if there are any performance issues or other disadvantages. Please check this link for an implementation.
https://medium.com/rahasak/publish-events-from-cassandra-to-kafka-via-cassandra-triggers-59818dcf7eed

Another approach is to use Cassandra Kafka Connectors but never have used that. Not sure how to architect this solution using this connector.

Comment: Both approaches sound like they need Kafka. So, did you try either? What specific issues are you having?

Answer (score 1):

Having written a trigger before, I can say that I would *not* recommend that path.

Cassandra has recently *significantly* improved its change data capture (CDC) feature, which I think is a better approach for what you're trying to do.  Basically, any changes to a table produce events that end up on a streaming topic.  And then you could use those however you need to.

DataStax (my employer) has a [CDC Agent](https://github.com/datastax/cdc-apache-cassandra) which is designed to run on each Cassandra node.  The agent:

- Watches the `commitlog/cdc_raw` directory for mutations.
- Fetches the changed rows.
- Writes the data rows onto an [Apache Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/) topic.
- Removes the corresponding file(s) from the `commitlog/cdc_raw` directory.

More documentation on this process can be found here: [About CDC for Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cdc-for-cassandra/cdc-apache-cassandra/2.2.1/index.html)

You'll want to make sure that `cdc_enabled` is set to `true` in each cassandra.yaml file.  The rest of the process is laid out in the repo's [quickstart guide](https://github.com/datastax/cdc-apache-cassandra/blob/master/QUICKSTART.md).

The CDC Agent is designed to work with [Apache Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/), not Kafka.  Standing up a Pulsar instance isn't terribly difficult.  But I'm sure if you wanted to use Kafka, you could have a look at the [repo](https://github.com/datastax/cdc-apache-cassandra) and figure out how to make it work with Kafka.

FWIW, here's how WalMart handled Cassandra CDC -> Kafka: [WalMart's Cassandra CDC Solution](https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/walmarts-cassandra-cdc-solution-6fc650031a3)